# Assistance with a PHP calculator

Tags: php

Okay, so I'm trying to make the calculator so $person1 and $person2 get added together, and then multiplied by 4. However, when I use this method, I test it by putting 1000 in one field, 1000 in the other and the result is "5000" when it should be "8000", yet I cannot seem to figure out why.

I tried adding "* 4;" to the $answer rather than having the $multivar variable, yet still the same issue.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['person1'])) $person1 = $_POST['person1'];
if (isset($_POST['person2'])) $person2 = $_POST['person2'];
$multivar = 4;
$answer = $person1 + $person2 * $multivar;

echo <<<_END
<form method='post' action='index.php'>
<table border='0' width='500px' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1' class="table">
<tr class="calcheading"><td colspan="2"><strong>How much can you borrow?</strong></td></tr>
<tr class="calcrow"><td>Person 1 income:</td><td align="center"><input type='text' name='person1' value="$person1"/></td></tr>
<tr class="calcrow2"><td>Person 2 income</td><td align="center"><input type='text' name='person2' value="$person2"/></td></tr>
<tr class="submit"><td colspan="2"><input type='submit' value='Calculate'/></td></tr>
_END;
?>

<tr class="calcrow">
<td><i>You can borrow up to:</td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo round($answer)?>"></td></i>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
$answer = ($person1 + $person2) * $multivar;
```

Multiplication is done before addition, so you have to use parentheses if you want the addition to happen first.

Comment: Order of operations. PEMDAS. Parenthesis, Exponent, Multiplication & Division, Addition & Subtraction.  I learned it as Please Excuse My Dear Aunt Sally.

Comment: Ah! That's where I was going wrong then. Silly beginner mistakes. Thank you for taking the time to answer this :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mischa, but a little bit more detail is that order of operations is coming into play here - "PEMDAS".  Formulas in parentheses get calculated first, then exponents, then multiplication/division across the line, then addition/subtraction across the line.  So what you had written earlier was actually calculated like: `1000+1000*4` which, to the compiler looks like `1000+4000` since the multiplication is performed first.  Actual code should be `$answer=($person1+$person2)*$multiplier`.